# Convert Numbers to Hyphenated Words in Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have a project that is requiring me to convert numbers to words, but the key is to convert numbers like: 23 to Twenty-Three, not Twenty Three. I've found [this script](http://ravindersinghdang.blogspot.com/2013/04/convert-numbers-into-words-using.html) which works great, except the it doesn't hyphenate the words. What would be the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

**Edit**

It needs to convert numbers like: 142 to One Hundred Forty-Two, not One Hundred Forty Two or One-Hundred-Forty-Two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bunch of good answers, but none of them go up beyond 4 or 5 digits... Here's what I ended up doing to get my project done.

```js
var th = ['', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion'];
var dg = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
var tn = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'];
var tw = ['twenty-', 'thirty-', 'forty-', 'fifty-', 'sixty-', 'seventy-', 'eighty-', 'ninety-'];

function toWords(s) {
    s = s.toString();
    s = s.replace(/[\, ]/g, '');
    if (s != parseFloat(s)) return 'not a number';
    var x = s.indexOf('.');
    if (x == -1) x = s.length;
    if (x > 15) return 'too big';
    var n = s.split('');
    var str = '';
    var sk = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 2) {
            if (n[i] == '1') {
                str += tn[Number(n[i + 1])] + ' ';
                i++;
                sk = 1;
            } else if (n[i] != 0) {
                str += tw[n[i] - 2] + ' ';
                sk = 1;
            }
        } else if (n[i] != 0) {
            str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
            if ((x - i) % 3 == 0) str += 'hundred ';
            sk = 1;
        }
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 1) {
            if (sk) str += th[(x - i - 1) / 3] + ' ';
            sk = 0;
        }
    }
    if (x != s.length) {
        var y = s.length;
        str += 'point ';
        for (var i = x + 1; i < y; i++) str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
    }
    final = str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').replace(/- /g, '-');
    if (final.substring(final.length-1) == "-"){
        final = final.substring(0, final.length-1);
    }
    return final;
}

var i;
for (i = 15; i < 25; i++) {
    document.write(toWords(i) + '<br>');
}

document.write(toWords(2745635) + '<br>');
```

Comment: But numbers aren't always spoken as their literal translations, e.g. 1 can be one or first, 2 can be two or second, same with lots of numbers e.g. 21 (twenty–one or twenty first), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code which you found, split the result by space and join back by hypen:

```
toWords(23).split(' ').join('-');
```

Comment: This, or edit that script you found and anywhere you see them doing stuff with ' ', replace with '-'

Comment: Won't that replace every space with a hyphen though?

Answer (score 1):

This will do for short numbers (less than 20,000):

```
number_string.replace(/ty (\S)/g,'ty-$1');
```

If you might have numbers like "forty thousand and five", though, you'll have to be more specific:

```
number_string.replace(/ty (one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)/gi,'ty-$1');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a custom proposal for dashed numbers.

```js
function wordify(n) {
    var word = [],
        numbers = {
            1: 'One',
            2: 'Two',
            3: 'Three',
            4: 'Four',
            5: 'Five',
            6: 'Six',
            7: 'Seven',
            8: 'Eight',
            9: 'Nine',
            10: 'Ten',
            11: 'Eleven',
            12: 'Twelve',
            t3: 'Thir', // -teen, -ty
            t5: 'Fif',
            t8: 'Eigh',
            20: 'Twenty'
        },
        hundreds = 0 | (n % 1000) / 100,
        tens = 0 | (n % 100) / 10,
        ones = n % 10,
        part;

    if (n === 0) {
        return 'Zero';
    }
    if (hundreds) {
        word.push(numbers[hundreds] + ' Hundred');
    }
    if (tens === 0) {
        word.push(numbers[ones]);
    } else if (tens === 1) {
        word.push(numbers['1' + ones] || (numbers['t' + ones] || numbers[ones]) + 'teen');
    } else {
        part = numbers[tens + '0'] || (numbers['t' + tens] || numbers[tens]) + 'ty';
        word.push(numbers[ones] ? part + '-' + numbers[ones] : part);
    }
    return word.join(' ');
}

var i;
for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    document.write(wordify(i) + '<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `lastIndexOf` and `substr` functions

```
var num = toWords(23);
var index = num.lastIndexOf(' ');

if(index != -1) {
   num = num.substr(0, index) + "-" + num.substr(index);
}
```